# copy bash command history (recursive search commands) into Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a container which I am using interactively (`docker run -it`), in it, i have to run a pretty common set of commands, though not always in a set order, hence I cannot just run a script.

Thus, I would like for a way to have my commands in **recursive search** (`Ctrl+R`) be available in the Docker container.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's mount the history file into the container from the host so it's contains will get preserved the container death.

```
# In some directory
touch bash_history
docker run -v ./bash_history:/root/.bash_history:Z -it fedora /bin/bash
```

I would recommend to have separate bash history to the one that you use on the host for the safety reasons.

Answer (score -1):

I found helpful info in these questions:
[Docker and .bash_history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279862/docker-and-bash-history)
[Docker: preserve command history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530384/docker-preserve-command-history)
https://superuser.com/questions/1158739/prompt-command-to-reload-from-bash-history

They use docker volume mounts however, which mean that the container commands affect the local (host PC) commands, which I do not want.

It seems I will have to copy `~/.bash_history` from local into container which will make the history work 'one-way'.

**UPDATE: Working:**
`COPY your_command_script.sh some_folder/my_history`
`ENV HISTFILE myroot/my_history`
`RUN PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r"`

*Explanation*:
copy command script into a file in container
tell the shell to look at a different file for history
reload the history file